# Get List Values in JavaScript Remoting

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting

Hi folks,
          Can anyone tell me how to get the list of account names in visualforce page using java script remoting?
Below is my code

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.AccController.getAccountList}',

        function(result, event) {
            if (event.status) {
                var ListVariable = '"//I dono how to get the list in javascript"      

            }
        );
```

//Controller

```
@RemoteAction     
 global static List<Account> getAccountList(){     
      List<Account> accList=[select id,Name from account];   
      return accList;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's quite clearly explained in the [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm). Do you understand the code you've written ?

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.AccController.getAccountList}',
        function(result, event) {
            if (event.status) {
                var ListVariable = '"//I dono how to get the list in javascript"      

            }
        );
```

> The fully qualified remote action is a string that represents the
>   complete path to the remote action method, including namespace, base
>   class, and so on:
>   namespace[.BaseClass][.ContainingClass].ConcreteClass.Method. Use
>   $RemoteAction in an expression to automatically resolve the namespace,
>   for example {!$RemoteAction.MyController.getAccount}.
>
> Invocation parameters are the arguments used to perform the remote
>   method invocation, and are the same arguments used to make a standard
>   remoting call:
>
> - The parameters to send to the @RemoteAction method, if any.
> - The callback function, which handles the returned result.
> - Configuration details for the invocation, if any.

The second bulletpoint is the answer here, you're written the callback which has 2 parameters :

> Your callback function will receive as parameters an event object
>   representing the status of the remote call, and the result object
>   returned by the remote Apex method.
>
> Apex primitive data types returned by result—such as strings or
>   numbers—are converted to their JavaScript equivalents. Apex objects
>   that are returned are converted to JavaScript objects, while
>   collections are converted to a JavaScript array. Keep in mind that
>   JavaScript is case-sensitive, so id, Id, and ID are considered
>   different fields.

So if your remote apex method returns a `List<sObject>`,  the result parameter/variable in your JS will be an JS array containing those objects in JS objects. Basically:

```
var ListVariable =  result;
```

So there's also no real need to use an additional variable unless you consider that easier to understand and maintain.