# How to return the Array or List from RemoteAction Method to Javascript?

Tags: apex, javascript, remote-action

I have a Javascript code which is used to call the method of a Controller using the **`@RemoteAction`**.

This is my **Javascript** coding

```
var arr = new Array('123', '234');
arr.splice(0, 1);
arr.splice(0, 1);
processByteChunkArray(arr);
// Here i tried this to make sure the empty array is passing or not

function processByteChunkArray(getResult) {
    FileUploadController.attachBlob(getResult, function(result, event) {
        //Proceed if there were no errors with the remoting call
        if (event.status == true) {
            alert(result);//This alert is coming
            getResult = JSON.parse(result);
            alert(getResult);//This alert is NOT coming
            processByteChunkArray(getResult);
        } else {
            checkForUploads();
        }
    });
}
```

This is **Controller** Coding

```
global static List<Attachment> attachList = new List<Attachment>();
@RemoteAction
global static List<Attachment> attachBlob(List<Attachment> getResult) {
    Attachment att = new Attachment(
        ParentId = parentId,
        Body = EncodingUtil.Base64Decode(base64BlobValue),
        Name = fileName,
        ContentType = contentType
    );
    if (getResult.size() > 0) {
        for (Attachment atm: getResult) {
            try {
                atm.Body = EncodingUtil.Base64Decode(EncodingUtil.Base64Encode(atm.Body) + base64BlobValue);
                attachList.add(atm);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.debug('This is in IF CATCH Condition===>' + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return JSON.serialize(attachList);
    } else {
        try {
            attachList.add(att);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('This is in ELSE CATCH Condition' + e.getMessage());
        }
        return JSON.serialize(attachList);
    }
}
```

And now my problem is, the List that i am returning on the Controller Method is not coming to Javascript. I tried the Same coding returning the STRING and it is working perfectly. Why not **`List<Attachment>`**.

I tried returning both **`List<Attachment>`** and **`Attachment[]`** but with no result in the Javascript.
 **`Is there any difference between List and Array?`**

**UPDATE:**

I updated the coding according to the JSON Serialize and parse. The Serialize is working but the parse is not working. Is there any way to parse the String to an array again and i need to store that array in the **`getResult`** variable

Please help...

Comment: possible duplicate: [Get List Values in JavaScript Remoting](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56237/get-list-values-in-javascript-remoting)

Comment: How are you passing *Parentid,filename..* values?

Comment: @Praveen, I just posted what is necessary of my problem... There is a whole bunch of code actually. But i am sure my question explains my problem..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest return the JSON string from method like.. first serialize the list and return

```
global static String attachBlob(List<Attachment> getResult) {

   // your code 

   return JSON.serialize(attachList);
}
```

I am not sure but I guess you may need to parse the javascript variable ie. `result`

like this `JSON.parse(result)`. this will give you the array

Comment: Sounds perfect :)

Comment: @Ratan, Thanks for the response, Your **JSON.serialize(attachList);** is returning and even showing in alert. But i want to assign that result to the same getResult in the Javascript Coding. While i am using the **JSON.parse(result)** it is not restponding and just strucks the coding in javascript... Is there any way to parse the result in javascript?

Comment: @Subhash `JSON.parse(result)` this retrun JavaScript array.  what do you want? javascript array or simple JSON string ? can you show me the processByteChunkArray method structure

Comment: Hi @Ratan, I updated my question according to your answer and asked the question too.. Can you help me plz...

Comment: @Subhash parsing the json string to array `JSON.parse()` should work. you may be getting issue in further steps.. can you add some detail about the processByteChunkArray  method \

Comment: @Ratan, Yes I can give the details about processByteChunkArray method but with the alert results itself i can tell you that the `JSON.parse()` is not working. Anyway, this processByteChunkArray is in the Javascript static Resource File. Will that be a problem?

Comment: @Subhash join this chat room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41792/discussion-between-ratan-and-sahisfdc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42418/discussion-between-subhash-and-ratan).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Ratan [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/131144/20830), you need to explicitly set the `escape` attribute to `false` which is `true` by default.

```
FileUploadController.attachBlob(getResult, function(result, event) {
        //Proceed if there were no errors with the remoting call
        if (event.status == true) {
            alert(result);//This alert is coming
            getResult = JSON.parse(result);
            alert(getResult);//This alert is NOT coming
            processByteChunkArray(getResult);
        } else {
            checkForUploads();
        }
    },{escape:false});
```

Comment: Hi @Praveen, I ended with following error...Visualforce Remoting Exception: No such column 'attributes' on sobject of type Attachment....It is taking the attributes as a field in attachment object

Comment: It looks like you should remove the `attributes` property from each array element by iterating it an for-loop.

Comment: how to do that...? And it should not get override afterwards, because i am sending the same array to the controller method again and again until the whole file is entered into a List...

Comment: i don't think iterating over the attachment array element `getResult` and removing unnecessary properties like `attributes` would solve your issue.Since the body of the attachment expects an BLOB ,it would throw an error `VFRemote.js:117 Visualforce Remoting Exception: Internal Service Error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: It is better to create a `List<AttachWrapper>` wrapper class instead of `List<Attachment>` to hold `Attachment` and its `body` separately.where `body` should contain the base64 encoded string and rest of the info like `ParentId,ContentType...`

Comment: @Subhash did it work?

Comment: No @Praveen, It is not... It is hitting so many errors and also got the limitations from the RemoteAction Limits too... So in that matter of fact, It can't be done with simply and have so many limitations for sending files...But really thanks for your suggestion Praveen...https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_limits.htm

Comment: Ya i agree there's lot of limitation to upload a file using Remote Action limiting only to 4.3 MB file, which also can be done only using chunk approach.